# What is wrong with the format of createfolderarg() funtion of the dropbox v2 python api?

Tags: python, api, dropbox

def CreateDropboxFolder(Path,FolderName):

```
##Connect to Dropbox with Supplied Access token
    print('Connecting to Dropbox...')
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('')
    print('Connected to Dropbox')

##Reset Variables
    DirExists=False

    ##Set Directory
    TempDir=Path+FolderName
    print('Started Creating New Directory: ' + TempDir + ' ...')

    ##Check if Location exists
    print ('Searching for Existing Directory in '+ Path)
    for entry in dbx.files_list_folder(path=os.path.dirname(Path)).entries:
            print (entry.name)
            if(entry.name==FolderName):
                    DirExists=True
                    break

    ##If Folder Directory exists Skip Create Directory
    if DirExists==True:
            print ('Folder Already Exists')

    ##If Folder Directory exists Create Directory
    else:
            ##Create Client Directory
            print('Creating New Directory: ' + TempDir)
            dropbox.files.CreateFolderArg(os.path.dirname(TempDir))
            print('Created New Directory: ' + TempDir)

    return TempDir
```

every part works. except the aforementioned function. I have tried formatting the directory string so many ways but it just doesn't work. after 2 nights of frustration I am about to pull my hair out. 
I have been passing Path='/Projects/' which is an existing directory in the root of my dropbox folder and FolderName = 'test'.

Comment: "Doesn't work"? What happens? Be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CreateFolderArg` is, as the name suggests, a class that corresponds to the argument you would pass to create a folder. You're making an instance of that class but not doing anything with it.

I think you're probably looking for `dbx.files_create_folder(TempDir)`.

Comment: Thanks! I need to stop coding late night haha. what a silly mistake.